# Referencing variable loaded as an import in Aurelia

Tags: json, import, aurelia

I am trying to import a small json file that contains various strings that the program uses.
I can do a successful import:

```
import * as dwSTRINGS from './data/strings.json';
```

But cannot seem to reference the variable dwSTRINGS.
How do reference imported variables?

Comment: try `import { dwSTRINGS } from './data/strings.json';`

Comment: Are you able to modify the `.json` file freely?